# Is it permissible to touch, hug or kiss a family friend?

Tags: halal-haram, women

I am 15 years old and I have a family friend who is also 15 years old (20 days younger to me). We are friends since we were born. We know each other very well like our personal interests, habits and much more. We even like each others company.

So, is it halal for me to touch her, hug her, or kiss her?

Can I marry her in the near future (inshallah)?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it permissible to touch, hug or kiss a family friend?

No, this is strictly prohibited.

> Can I marry her in the near future (inshallah)?

Yes, if she is a not a mahram (e.g. if she is your cousin then it's halal for you to marry her). But if she is one of the following, then it is haram for you to marry her:

> ...their husbands, their fathers, their husbands' fathers, their sons,
> their husbands' sons, their brothers, their brothers' sons, their
> sisters' sons, their women, that which their right hands possess, or
> those male attendants having no physical desire, or children who are
> not yet aware of the private aspects of women. And let them not stamp
> their feet to make known what they conceal of their adornment. And
> turn to Allah in repentance, all of you, O believers, that you might
> succeed. -- Qur'an 24:31
>
> See [Mahram (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahram)  for a full list of mahrams.